# Python throwing KeyError when JQuery included

Tags: javascript, jquery, python

I have the code below, where I am wanting to set a variable within the html. For some reason, when I remove the JQuery, it works, but then when I put the JQuery script in, it doesn't. I think it may be because the JQuery is being called on loading the page, as I can get it to work if the JQuery is called from a button. I've tried %s, %(currentDate)s, {0} and then their relating output, but none of them seem to have worked. The first two throw `ValueError: unsupported format character ''' (0x27) at index 952`, and then {0} causes `KeyError: "\n                    $('"`

```
class Fitbit(object):
@cherrypy.expose
def index(self):

currentDate = (time.strftime("%d/%m/%Y"))

return """<html>
<head>
    <title>Fitbit</title>
    <link href="/static/css/fitbit.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script>
            $('document').ready(init);
                function init(){
                $('.bar-percentage[data-percentage]').each(function () {
                    var progress = $(this);
                    var percentage = Math.ceil($(this).attr('data-percentage'));
                    $({countNum: 0}).animate({countNum: percentage}, {
                        duration: 2000,
                        easing:'linear',
                        step: function() {
                        // What todo on every count
                            var pct = '';
                            if(percentage == 0){
                                pct = Math.floor(this.countNum) + '%';
                            }else{
                                pct = Math.floor(this.countNum+1) + '%';
                            }
                        progress.text(pct) && progress.siblings().children().css('width',pct);
                        }
                    });
                });
            };
        </script>
</head>

<body>

<h4>{0}</h4>

</body>

</html>""" .format(currentDate)

#return html
index.exposed = True
```

If I remove the JQuery, it's definitely working fine and displaying the date. Any other ideas of what to try would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are having a problem because of all the curly braces in your JavaScript. This is confusing the `format` function. You would be much better off using a [templating engine](https://cherrypy.readthedocs.org/en/3.2.6/progguide/choosingtemplate.html) to render your HTML.

However, if you want to continue with your current code, try putting the JavaScript/jQuery code into its own variable and then inserting it into your HTML with your `format` call.

```
currentDate = (time.strftime("%d/%m/%Y"))
javascript = """
$('document').ready(init);
function init(){
    $('.bar-percentage[data-percentage]').each(function () {
        var progress = $(this);
        var percentage = Math.ceil($(this).attr('data-percentage'));
        $({countNum: 0}).animate({countNum: percentage}, {
            duration: 2000,
            easing:'linear',
            step: function() {
            // What todo on every count
                var pct = '';
                if(percentage == 0){
                    pct = Math.floor(this.countNum) + '%';
                }else{
                    pct = Math.floor(this.countNum+1) + '%';
                }
            progress.text(pct) && progress.siblings().children().css('width',pct);
            }
        });
    });
};
"""

return """<html>
<head>
    <title>Fitbit</title>
    <link href="/static/css/fitbit.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script>{0}</script>
</head>

<body>

<h4>{1}</h4>

</body>

</html>""".format(javascript, currentDate)
```

Comment: Ah this is lovely! I was previously using a template engine, but I was having trouble with getting my CSS to play with it correctly, hence why I had to revert to this - which I hate because it's too much code in one place. Will have a look into the 3 in that link again, but the solution you put works too! Thanks!